# (Java) How to Split User Input String Into multiple Integers and Doubles

Tags: java, input

In the program I am asking for user input that the user will provide in the format of:

speed 12 health 99 power 50 accuracy .9

And split this and assign input into multiple integers and doubles (speed, health, power, accuracy) to be later used in a mathematical equation. How would I go about doing this (delimiters etc.)? I have researched the Scanner class but I can't find something that would help in this certain situation. 
I just want to be pointed in the right direction

Thank You

Comment: I would suggest `String.split()` and then `Integer.parseInt()` and `Double.parseDouble`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void calculate(String input){
    String[] inputAsArray = input.split(" ");


    int speed = Integer.valueOf(inputAsArray[1]).intValue();
    int health = Integer.valueOf(inputAsArray[3]).intValue();
    int power = Integer.valueOf(inputAsArray[5]).intValue();
    double accuracy = Double.valueOf(inputAsArray[7]).doubleValue();

}
//when order isn't specified and variables may be missing.
public void calculate2(String input){
    String[] inputAsArray = input.split(" ");
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < inputAsArray.length; i+= 2){
        map.put(inputAsArray[i], inputAsArray[i+1]);
    }

    int speed = -1;
    if(map.containsKey("speed")){
        speed = Integer.valueOf(map.get("speed")).intValue();
    }
    /*
     * OTHER VARIABLES NOT SHOWN. SAME FORMAT
     */
}
```

Comment: What about the input is different, say with `weight 100 speed 12 health 99 power 50 accuracy .9` your program would not work properlly for different inputs :) Think on that and update your answer.

Comment: It's not my question. The OP stated that the user input would be on that format which doesn't properlly state that it WILL NOT change, so you have to think on that on your answer as well. It was just a hint on how you should think how to answer here on SO :) don't get upset :) ! Now it worth +1

Comment: Can you explain why it isn't in the main method? And what should be in the main mehtod?

Comment: You can put this code in your main method or call this function from the main method depending on your needs. Also, some people have preferences to where they put their code. You can imagine that some people want their main method to have as little code as possible for modularity. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

This code scannes a line from sysin and converted it to a map of key values pairs:

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input =sc.nextLine();
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s+(\\d*\\.*\\d*)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); 
  while (m.find()) {
    map.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
  }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a design outline that encapsulates the statistics in a `Stats` class, and uses an enumeration to limit the input statistic names. In this example, we use a Scanner to read the statistics from standard input.

```
class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter stats: ");
        Stats stats = new Stats();
        int statCount = Stat.values().length;
        java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < statCount; i++) {
            String statName = scanner.next();
            Stat stat = Stat.valueOf(statName);
            stat.set(stats, scanner);
            System.out.println(stats);
        }
    }

    static class Stats {
        int speed, health, power;
        float accuracy;

        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(50);
            for (Stat stat: Stat.values()) {
                sb.append(stat).append(' ').append(stat.get(this)).append(' ');
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    enum Stat {
        speed, health, power, accuracy;

        String get(Stats stats) {
            switch(this) {
                case speed: return String.valueOf(stats.speed);
                case health: return String.valueOf(stats.health);
                case power: return String.valueOf(stats.power);
                case accuracy: return String.valueOf(stats.accuracy);
                default: throw new IllegalStateException(String.valueOf(this));
            }
        }

        double set(Stats stats, Scanner scanner) {
            switch (this) {
                case speed: return stats.speed = scanner.nextInt();
                case health: return stats.health = scanner.nextInt();
                case power: return stats.power = scanner.nextInt();
                case accuracy: return stats.accuracy = scanner.nextFloat();
                default: throw new IllegalStateException(String.valueOf(this));
            }
        }
    }
}
```